# SonarQube. What oracle DB component can be removed

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

We use Oracle DB as sonarqube database and found out that list of oracle components installed. What components can be safely removed?

List of components:

COMP_ID     COMP_NAME

APEX        Oracle Application Express

EM          Oracle Enterprise Manager

ORDIM       Oracle Multimedia

XDB         Oracle XML Database

CONTEXT     Oracle Text

EXF         Oracle Expression Filter

RUL         Oracle Rules Manager

OWM         Oracle Workspace Manager

CATALOG     Oracle Database Catalog Views

CATPROC     Oracle Database Packages and Types

JAVAVM      JServer JAVA Virtual Machine

XML         Oracle XDK

CATJAVA     Oracle Database Java Packages

Comment: Why do you want to remove these components? Clarify your question...

Comment: Do you have any requirement from the software so to decide which components you need and don't?

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube didn't install one or many Oracle components. They can be installed during the creation process of the database or after (but always explicitly).
SonarQube works perfectly with the minimum and mandatory Oracle components :

1. Oracle Database Catalog
2. Oracle Database packages and Types
3. Oracle XML Database

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!